# Sorting function isn't working

Tags: c++, sorting

EDIT: OK I've gotten it to swap, but it seems to be swapping based on title rather than length. This is the current output:

```
Title3, Url3, Comment3, 5.8, ***
Title2, Url2, Comment2, 9.3, ****
Title1, Url1, COmment1, 2.3, ****
```

And this is what the current function looks like:

```
if (sort == "length") { //order based on length
    for (int last = size -1; last > 0; last --) 
    {
        for (int cur = 0; cur < last; cur ++) 
        {
            if (!videos[cur]->longer(videos[cur+1])) {
                cout << "it's swapping" << endl;
                swap(videos[cur], videos[cur+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I'm trying to create an array of videos, including the video title, URL, a comment, the length of the video, and a rating. I'm also allowing the user to sort the video by length, rating, or title. For now I'm just trying to sort it by length, which isn't working. This is my input:

```
length
Title1
http://www.youtube.com
Comment ONE
2.3
4
Title2
http://www.youtube.com
Comment TWO
9.4
2
Title3
http://www.youtube.com
Comment THREE
5.7
3
```

And this is my current output:

```
Title1, http://www.youtube.com, Comment ONE, 2.3, ****
Title2, http://www.youtube.com, Comment TWO, 9.4, **
Title3, http://www.youtube.com, Comment THREE, 5.7, ***
```

This is what my output SHOULD be:

```
Title2, http://www.youtube.com, Comment TWO, 9.4, **
Title3, http://www.youtube.com, Comment THREE, 5.7, ***
Title1, http://www.youtube.com, Comment ONE, 2.3, ****
```

Since 9.4 is the largest length, it should be on top. Since 2.3 is the shortest length, it should be on the bottom.

```
int main()
{
    const int MAX = 100; //setting max value
    Video * videos[MAX]; //100 limit
    int size = 0; //initalizing "size" at 0.
    string titletemp; 
    string linktemp; 
    string commenttemp; 
    double lengthtemp; 
    int ratingtemp;
    string sort;

    cin >> sort; //sorting preference

    if ((sort != "length") && (sort != "rating") && (sort != "title")) { //checking to see if they used the right input
        cerr << sort << " is not a legal sorting method, giving up." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) 
    {
        getline(cin, titletemp); //getting title from user
        if ( cin.eof() ) { //breaking if ctrl + d is used
            break;
        } else if ( !cin ) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
        getline(cin, linktemp); //repeating for all other fields
        if ( cin.eof() ) {
            break;
        } else if ( !cin ) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
        getline(cin, commenttemp);
        if ( cin.eof() ) {
            break;
        } else if ( !cin ) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
        cin >> lengthtemp;
        if ( cin.eof() ) {
            break;
        } else if ( !cin ) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
        cin >> ratingtemp;
        if ( cin.eof() ) {
            break;
        } else if ( !cin ) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
        cin.ignore();
        videos[i] = new Video(titletemp, linktemp, commenttemp, lengthtemp, ratingtemp);
        size++; //increase the size of array, assuming the for loop hasn't been broken
    }   
    if (sort == "length") { //order based on length
        for (int last = size -1; last > 0; last --) 
        {
            for (int cur = 0; cur < last; cur ++) 
            {
                if (videos[cur]->longer(videos[cur+1])) {
                    swap(videos[cur], videos[cur+1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //print all the ordered videos
    {
        videos[i]->print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the this is the "longer" function from the video.cpp file:

```
bool Video::longer(Video *other)
{
    return m_length > other->m_length;
}
```

m_length is a double pointer in the header file.

```
double * m_length;
```

Does anyone know why this isn't sorting? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like you have made a serious attempt to debug your code. If you had, you would have a lot less code ([mcve]) and observations made while [stepping through the MCVE with the debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that came with your development environment. Debugger use and applying divide and conquer approaches like MCVE are critical skills to a programmer. Until you get good at using them you will be slow.

Comment: Or you could just use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and be done.

Comment: You mean the constant if (eof) statements, right? I originally had that in a while loop, but it was creating problems with the print function, causing it to repeat itself each time. I'm going to go back and see if I can figure out what went wrong once I can get the code to at least function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem lies in `length` being a pointer. Make it just `double` instead of `double *`. `double *` will store it as an address. Just `double` will work fine.

I think compiler should have given a warning on assigning `double` to `double *`.

For the above, change

```
double * m_length;
```

to

```
double m_length;
```

Following condition should be

```
if (videos[cur]->longer(videos[cur+1]))
```

should be

```
if (!videos[cur]->longer(videos[cur+1]))
```

Former condition will push video of longer length to the end. Here, we want to push shorter video to the end.

Comment: Sorry for hasty reply. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! But as it is, the videos don't seem to be sorting themselves at all properly or otherwise.

Comment: if(videos[cur] && videos[cur]->longer(videos[cur+1]) just to be safe.

Comment: Updated the answer. This might help.

Comment: Oddly enough it didn't warn me at all. Really weird, usually the compiler goes nuts about stuff like that. It's sorting now but is based on the title for some reason. I editted the question.